# Why does c() take two vectors and output one?

Tags: r, vector

In my course exercises, I have encountered the code below and can't figure out why `c()` takes two vectors and outputs only one. Obviously, it is combining the two conditions <0.5 and >0.5 (missing = 0.5 btw). I'm not sure how `c()` is used here.
thank you

```
func=function(n) {
  u=runif(n)
  return(c(0.5*log(2*u[u<0.5]),
           -0.5*log(2*(1-u[u>0.5]))) )
}
output <- func(5000)
```

I'm expecting `c()` to return two vectors

Comment: That is expected behavior for `c()`. You probably need to use `list()`.

Comment: If you evaluate `?c` in an R console you will see that `'c'` stands for `'combine'`. It would thus be surprising if `c` *didn't* combine the two vectors.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a simple "read the help for c()" question, as the previous comment suggests.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. when we use c() this way: x<-c(1,2), x returns is a 'list' with two values 1,2 and does not 'combine' them. the above code also has two numbers in c() . Why is the above treated differently?

Comment: No, it's not a list, it's a vector with two entries.  It is what you get when you combine two vectors with one entry each.

Comment: @LenGreski, I don't think that's a good reason to close the question.  There may be others besides the OP who don't understand what `c()` does.

Comment: Im not sure why the confusion... c() behaves how it is supposed to. It takes everything inside and concatenate it. so if you put two numeric areguments, they appear as one big vector. if you want them seperate, you should explicitly create two vectors, not just one.

Comment: @user2554330 - [How much research effort is expected of Stackoverflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) clearly expects people to read the relevant R help files before asking a question. Therefore, this question is not appropriate for SO, and should be closed.

Comment: `1` and `2` are vectors of length 1 (e.g. `is.vector(1)` returns `TRUE`), so `c(1,2)` is an example of combining two smaller vectors to get a larger vector.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe just put it in a list instead of a vector?

```
func=function(n) {
  u=runif(n)
  return(list("1"=(0.5*log(2*u[u<0.5])),
          "2"= -0.5*log(2*(1-u[u>0.5])) ))
}
output <- func(10)
```